# Did I solve $z^{n-1}=\overline{z}$ correctly?

Tags: complex-analysis

> Please could someone tell me if my solution of $z^{n-1}=\overline{z}$
>   is correct?

My solution:

We have $z^{n-1} =\overline{z}$ if and only if $z^{n-1}z =\overline{z}z$, so

$z^n = |z|^2$

In polar coordinates,

$$ r^n e^{i n \varphi}  = r^2$$

or, equivalently,

$$ r^{n-2} e^{i n \varphi}  = 1$$

This equation implies that $r=1$. Hence we are taking $n$-th roots of $1$:

$$e^{i n \varphi}  = 1$$

So the resulting set is a discrete and finite subset of the unit circle (consisting of the $n$-th roots of $1$).

Comment: What about  $n=2$?

Comment: What about $z=0$?

Comment: could you please add more information, like where is n?

Comment: @leonbloy $r$ is a radius in polar coordinates, assumed to be nonnegative.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume $n$ stands for a positive integer.

If $n=1$, the equation is $1=\bar{z}$.

If $n=2$, the equation is $z=\bar{z}$, so any real number is a solution.

Suppose $n>2$. First of all, $z=0$ is a solution. Assume now $z\ne0$ and write it as $z=re^{i\varphi}$. The equation becomes
$$
r^{n-1}e^{i(n-1)\varphi}=re^{-i\varphi}
$$
Since $r>0$, we can write it as
$$
r^{n-2}e^{in\varphi}=1
$$
Since $n>2$, we get $r=1$ and $e^{in\varphi}=1$, so the $n$-th roots of unity are the solutions.

---

If $n$ is allowed to be any integer, the case $n=0$ becomes $z\bar{z}=1$, so any complex number of modulus $1$ is a solution.

If $n<0$, write $w=1/z$ and $m=-n$, so the equation becomes
$$
\frac{1}{w^{m+1}}=\frac{1}{\bar{w}}
$$
or
$$
w^{m+1}=\bar{w}
$$
and we're in the same situation as before with $n>2$ (but, of course, the solution $0$ cannot be considered).

Comment: Z=0 works iff n is not 1, right?

Comment: @Ron Yes, I'll fix. Thanks.